# How to unbrick my motorola moto g if it does not power on?

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I use motorola moto g xt1033. I tried to root it and upgrade it to lollipop 5.0, while rooting it suddenly stopped and then i unpluged the data cable in between and tried to power on it but it does not do any thing. So i even pluged it on charge but only a led white light blinks continuesly and do nothing no response same i also tried connecting again it on pc but it does the same thing.. i also tried to bring the boot option with pressing power button along with volume down button for like 5mins but it was of no use nothing responded. But when i plug it with a datacable on my pc on the pc screen it shows conected and it stays conected just for 1min and again the led starts flashing on and off anc in pc it shows connected again disconected. Please help me with this problem..

Comment: same problem here...did u resolve this ?